# Как логировать warnings и errors, на удаленных устройствах?

Tags: android

Но не те, что я прописал в коде, например:

```
Log.e("myTAG","Something was wrong ....");
```

А те, что Android сам генерирует в роцесе работы
Уточнение: Удаленно - это значит я не могу подключить устройство и посмотреть данные в студии

Comment: Они и так все логируются. Будет видно, если отключить фильтр для вашего приложения в Android Monitor. И что значит удалённые устройства?

Comment: Это значит что я не могу их подключить и смотреть логи через Android Monitor

Comment: Используй системы для анализа приложений, например [Google Analytics для Android](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v4/exceptions?hl=ru). Ну так и логируй пойманной исключение, а не свой текст.

Comment: А как сейчас вы смотрите те, что сами прописали `Log.e("myTAG","Something was wrong ....");`?

Comment: https://mobikul.com/track-android-app-exceptions-crashes-google-analytics-v4-chapter-2/

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31421865/how-to-send-android-app-logs-to-remote-server 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/601503/how-do-i-obtain-crash-data-from-my-android-application